# miktex-makepk consistently fails to install fonts

Tags: fonts, miktex, texstudio

I'm trying to use new typefaces with TeXstudio/MiKTeX, but every single time I try to use one from TeXLive that I install (which is done automatically for any package I include in the preamble that's in TeXLive) TeXstudio gives me an error from the `miktex-makepf` command.

This is the output I get when using Paratype Serif:

```
Trying to make PK font PTSerif-Regular-tlf-ot1 at 480 DPI...

Running miktex-makemf.exe...

miktex-makemf: The PTSerif-Regular-tlf-ot source file could not be found. Running ttf2pk.exe...

miktex-makepk

: PK font PTSerif-Regular-tlf-ot1 could not be created.

Process exited with error(s)
```

Can someone please tell me what's going on?

Comment: THe message means at leeast that MiKTeX doesn't know of a type 1 font named PTSerif-Regular. Why did you install the TeX Live version instead of MiKTeX's with MiKTeX package manager?

Comment: @bernard, I didn't install anything. I just called the packages with `\usepackage` and MiKTeX installed it itself. Maybe I'm unsure of what TeXLive is. I assumed it was the common collection of packages or something. I'm new to LaTeX.

Comment: Sound as if you have local map files which are not updated. Run in a command line `updmap`.

Comment: @ulrikefischer, ah maybe that has something to do with it. I made a local texmf directory but couldn't get manually installed fonts to work with MiKTeX despite instructions,  so I abandoned it. Will merely typing updmap in console fix it?

Comment: OK. First check whether it's installed (with MPM). Then run from the command line, as administrator and as user, `updmap --verbose`. It then should work without launching `makepk`, which has nothing to do with font installation: it tries to create bitmap fonts.

Comment: Using `updfont` worked. Thank you both.

Answer (score 7):

This problem was caused because I'm in a multiuser environment and failed to update the local map files.

The problem was solved by running the `updmap` command from the console.

Comment: This has nothing to do with a local texmf trees but is a consequence of a multiuser installation. In such installations the normal user often has its own map-files which must be updated by the user with `updmap` after a font installation.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thanks for the clarification. I edited the answer.