# The futb8r source file could not be found - how to fix this error?

Tags: fonts, texstudio

I wanted to change the default font to Utopia, I saw how to do it [here](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/utopia-fouriermath/), so I copy&pasted the lines from the **Usage** chapter of that link:

```
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
```

And nothing works...I just get the following error:

> Sorry, but miktex-makepk did not succeed for the following reason: PK
>   font futb8r could not be created.

In the log file this is written:

```
2018-07-21 17:11:40,471+0200 INFO  miktex-makemf - starting with command line: miktex-makemf.exe --verbose futb8r
2018-07-21 17:11:40,471+0200 FATAL miktex-makemf - The futb8r source file could not be found.
```

I'm using TeXstudio 2.12.10 on Windows 10.

```
\documentclass[]{report}
%Import packages and settings
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{color}
%\input{pkgs}
%Import variables
%\input{variables}

% ************ DOCUMENT BEGINS

\begin{document}
%   \include{titlepage}            
    %   Abbildungen
%   \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\listfigurename}
%   \listoffigures  
    %   Tabellen 
%   \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\listtablename}
%   \listoftables
    %   Abkürzungen
%   \makenomenclature
%   \printnomenclature[9em]
%   \include{chapters/abstract}
    \tableofcontents
    \include{chapters/introduction}
    \include{chapters/methods}
    \include{chapters/overview}
    \include{chapters/findings}
    \include{chapters/conclusion}
    % Set bib style and add bib
    \bibliographystyle{abbrv}
    \bibliography{lit}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Is package fourier  installed?

Comment: Is this (→ https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/209430/miktex-makepk-consistently-fails-to-install-fonts) similar to your case?

Comment: @DG' I'm not really in a "multiuser environment" as far as I know, so I guess no

Comment: @Bernard can't TeXStudio install everything that's missing automatically? It did install a lot of pkgs when I first compiled this, so I expected it to have everything loaded. I don't know if it's installed, where do I have to check? My Windows10 font folder?

Comment: To check whether it is installed, load MiKTeX console/ Package manager, and type `fourier` in the editing window.  If fourier is installed, this means the compiler doesn't find the type1 version of the font; i.e. `dvips.map` and friends were not updated when the font was installed. Refresh Fontmap files fromMiKTeX console (`Tasks` menu).

Comment: @Bernard I don't know how to load MiKTeX console/ Package manager. I also don't see a menu called tasks, or in my case something like "Aufgaben", since my TeXStudio is in German.

Comment: The menu `Tasks` is a menu from  MiKTeX Console. As to the latter, you should have a MiKTeX 2.9 menu in  the Start Menu, and MiKTeX Console is a submenu (b.t.w., I suppose you're under Windows – is that correct?).

Comment: I found the MiKTeX Package Manager in my StartMenu and I searched and found 'fourier' and 'fouriernc'...fourier is already installed since that option under 'Task' is grayed out, but fouriernc apparently isn't. Should I install that, or what do I click to refresh the fontmap files, as you mentioned?

Comment: `Fouriernc` is not necessary, unless you want to use `New Century Schoolbook` for text and fourier for maths. In MiKteX console you have also the installation date. To refresh the font map files, it's a submenu of the Tasks menu (in the tool bar of the Console). Maybe you'll have to do it both as `User` and as `Admin`, depending on your installation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how to refresh fontmap files from within MiKTeX Console (depending on your installation, you may have to do it as Administrator or as User):

[image]

Comment: Thanks, so they first problem I realized I had: MiKTeX Console was not in my StartMenu, only Package Manager and Settings - so I reinstalled it completely - and after I refreshed the font map files as USER it finally worked! :)

Comment: Did you have an old installation?

Comment: I don't think so, it was something with 2.9 as well, but I must have messed some stuff up - when installing it the first time there was an error because TeXStudio was still open, after I closed everything it worked. I guess maybe I had and ignored that same error during my first installation and since then never had that Console and maybe other things were missing due to it too

Comment: MiKTeX 2.9 was out in october 2010, whereas MiKTeX Console, such as it is now, was out  only a few months ago.